# Is there an easier way to call booleans from php?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to call a tinyInt from my server while converting it to a boolean.

Is there an easier way to do this than what I am using?

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<td>",
         "<input type=\"checkbox\" id='switch-state' name=\"$row[name]\" state=\"<script boolean(<? echo '$row[state]'; ?>) </script>\" </td>";
}
```

Comment: What is the intended output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all kinds of wrong.

- You can't put a `<script>` tag inside an HTML attribute. This is actually horrible.
- You can't have multiple HTML elements with the same ID. When in a loop, use a counter to generate unique IDs.
- You should pass all string data you output to HTML through [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) to avoid breaking the result HTML and to minimize the risk of XSS vulnerabilities.
- You might want to use something other than non-standard attributes (such as  `state="…"`) to transport extra data in an element. 
  HTML5's `data-*` attributes would be a good fit (`data-state="…"`). Another option would be a CSS class, for example. That depends on what you intend to do with the state information.
- JavaScript can handle numbers just fine. When used in Boolean context, `0` evaluates to `false`, all other numbers evaluate to `true`. You might want to transport server data as it is, instead of translating it.

Here's what I would do.

```
$index = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $index++;
    echo "<td>",
        "<input type='checkbox' ", 
            "id='switch-state-$index' ",
            "name='".htmlspecialchars($row['name'])."' ",
            "data-state='".$row['state']}."'",
        "></td>\n";
}
```

which outputs:

```
<td><input type='checkbox' id='switch-state-1' name='foo' data-state='1'></td>
<td><input type='checkbox' id='switch-state-2' name='bar' data-state='0'></td>
```

Comment: With the data-state i recieve an error saying the brackets shouldn't be there. Is that because it is echoing those as well?

Comment: @Brandon I've modified my answer a bit, I had made a mistake in that string interpolation syntax myself. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

shorthand php would be good here

```
//Add this bit and reformat your statement
echo ($row['state'] == 1) ? "true" : "false";

$format = "<td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%f</td><td>%f</td><td><input type=\"checkbox\" id='switch-state' name=\"%s\" state=\"%s\" </td>";

$data = sprintf($format, $row['city'], $row['name'], $row['lat'], $row['long'], $row['name'], ($row['state'] == 1) ? "true":"false" );

echo $data;
```

Comment: Can you explain to me `($row['state'] == 1) ? "true":"false" );`

Comment: Its basically an if statement and produces the result, so the bit in brackets is the test, then after the question mark if its true and after the colon if its false